# How to plot these points in shape correctly?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, graph

I have 2 variables:
NUMBER OF STAGES (S): between 1 and 30
 TRUE POSITIVE RATE (TPR):always between 0.8 and 1
 and FALSE POSITIVE RATE (FPR) :between 0 and 1

When i get TPR and FPR i must claculate ( TPR^S ) and (FPR^S), and plot a graph then get other values of them and plot in the same figure, to do a comparison.

```
numstages=12;
TPR=0.995;
FPR=0.5;

for i=1:numstages
    TPRstage(i)=(TPR^i);
    FPRstage(i)=(FPR^i);
end


TPRstage=fliplr(TPRstage);
FPRstage=fliplr(FPRstage);


figure;
plot(FPRstage,TPRstage,'-');
```

[image]

```
figure;

plot( FPRstage, TPRstage, '+r' ); % plot the original points
n = numel(FPRstage); % number of original points
xi = interp1( 1:n, FPRstage, linspace(1, n, 10*n) ); % new sample points 
yi = interp1(   FPRstage, TPRstage, xi );
hold all;
plot( xi, yi ); % should be smooth between the original points
```

[image]

As you see in the picture, this is a plot of the same value of TPR and 3 of FPR: 0.2 , 0.3 , 0.5  .
I want the X and Y axes to be between [0,1].
when FPR is 0.3 or 0.2 its stop there, i want the line to go horizontaly to 1 of X, and to start from (0 , 0) .
Similair to this one:
[image]

And the size between 0 and 0.8 smaller unalf to see the changes in the graph between 0.8 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For x-axis. I have appended `0` to beginning and `1` to end of array `xi`.

```
xi=[0 xi 1];
```

For y-axis. The plot is starting from `0.94` in y-axis. So I have appended `0.93` to beginning and `1` at the end of `yi`.

```
yi=[0.93 yi 1];
```

Then changed the label of `0.93` to `0`.

```
set(gca,'YTick',[0.93 0.94 0.95 0.96 0.97 0.98 0.99 1]);
set(gca,'YTickLabel',{'0','0.94','0.95','0.96','0.97','0.98','0.99','1'});
```

Here is the updated code.

```
figure
for index=1:3
FPRarray=[0.2 0.3 0.5];

numstages=12;
TPR=0.995;
FPR=FPRarray(index);

for i=1:numstages
    TPRstage(i)=(TPR^i);
    FPRstage(i)=(FPR^i);
end


TPRstage=fliplr(TPRstage);
FPRstage=fliplr(FPRstage);

n = numel(FPRstage); % number of original points
xi = interp1( 1:n, FPRstage, linspace(1, n, 10*n) ); % new sample points 
yi = interp1(   FPRstage, TPRstage, xi );
hold all;

xi=[0 xi 1];
yi=[0.93 yi max(yi)];
plot( xi, yi ); % should be smooth between the original points
set(gca,'YTick',[0.93 0.94 0.95 0.96 0.97 0.98 0.99 1]);
set(gca,'YTickLabel',{'0','0.94','0.95','0.96','0.97','0.98','0.99','1'});
end
```

Comment: i can't see anything they are small . @Rijul Sudhir

Comment: It is because of the values in `TPRstage` and `FPRstage`. If value have no meaning then you can normalize it to `0` and `1`.

Comment: can't understand it and your modification showing the lines in top of axes  @Rijul Sudhir

Comment: Does only shape matters? You don't care about real values?

Comment: i care of them both, i want to minimize the y axes between 0 and 0.8 to see well the rest [0.8 1].

Comment: @ Rijul Sudhir  thats better, but i want the line to continue to 1 of X not (1,1)  that mean from max value of FPR to 1 : for exemple (max(FPR),TPR)-------> (0.5 , 0.995) the Y stay fix 0.955 and x go to 1 horizontaly

Comment: @matlab22 change `yi=[0.93 yi 1];` to `yi=[0.93 yi max(yi)];`

Comment: @ Rijul Sudhir Thank you sir very much for you effort. @Ander Biguri lol Thank you too